# How to call REST APIs from Razor pages web app

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

Let's say I have two web applications, the first one is Razor pages application and the second one is web api application and both are ASP.NET Core apps

I've being checking few answers and approaches of how to call an api from Rzaor pages app and as far as I understood, there are two ways of doing so:

1. I can call the APIs through `JQuery` or `JavaScript` by doing ajax/fetch requests.
2. I can call the APIs from the ActionResult before returning the page using HTTP client.

But I think there is a better way to do it, am I missing something here or the above two options are everything? Noting that the two applications are separated and should remain separated (can't have them in one project or as one application)

Comment: To think of it another way... You can call your API from client-side code, or you can call it from server-side code.  What third alternative are you looking for?  Where in your application's logic do you want to get data from the API and what prevents you from doing that?  It's not really clear to me what the actual problem is here.

Comment: Your 1 and 2 statements are true, another one whether we can add two application in one solution, yes this is aslo possible totally depends on requirement and needs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.